# Auto-update a google form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Is it possible to write code that automatically changes the questions on a Google Form? Would love to be able to automatically sync our signup form with a spreadsheet which lists the chapters around the world.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

From [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.